# Browser cache my route

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, akka, akka-http

I have a server written on Scala and Akka http.
I have a route that returns a 308 Permanent Redirect with presigned url to download file in s3

example:

```
https://bucket.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/completed/empty.txt.zip?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20180714T122049Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=59&X-Amz-Credential=credential%2Feu-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=signature
```

expiration time of this url is 60 minutes

The problem is that my browser caches my route(server doesn't generate url with new credentials), and returns old presigned url that has expired.

Adding header param Cache-control: no-cache does not resolve my problem, because people follow link not from site

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you checked with something like curl, that it is actually a 302 and not a 301?

Comment: @colde, yes , it was 308 not 302, I fix it.